# Returning multiple values in JS

Tags: javascript, function, return, return-value, multiple-value

I was just tweaking some code in JS and ended up writing the below code.

```
const adding=(a,b,c,d)=> {
  return(a+b, c+d)
}

let sum1, sum2 = adding(1,2,3,4)
console.log(sum1)
console.log(sum2)
```

The output was
Undefined
7

And when I changed the position of return values like below

```
const adding=(a,b,c,d)=> {
  return(c+d, a+b)
}

let sum1, sum2 = adding(1,2,3,4)
console.log(sum1)
console.log(sum2)
```

The out put was Undefined 3

My question is Why?

Comment: It made the topic clearer, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach returns only the last expression, because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and parentheses is not a valid data type, just a [grouping operator `()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping).

Instead you could take an array as data structure with further [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const adding = (a, b, c, d) => [c + d, a + b];

let [sum1, sum2] = adding(1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log(sum1)
console.log(sum2)
```

Comment: Thank you, It makes sense. I thought of comma as a separator but forgot it is an operator too.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can declare multiple variables on a single line separated with comma. Therefore you declared **sum1**  and **sum2**. However, you assigned value to only **sum2**

What you did is same as

```
let sum1;
let sum2 = add(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: But why the second return value is assigned to sum2, not the first return value.

Comment: Now I know why sum1 is undefined, Thank you.